# How to configure Springboot with camunda enterprise edition?

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I am facing issue while configuring springboot with camunda enterprise edition
project is not able to resolve the dependency for "camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-ee"
Can anybody suggest, if anything i missed to configure

Please find the below configuration

In pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <camunda.version>3.3.6</camunda.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.example.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project-camunda</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${camunda.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${camunda.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>camunda-bpm-nexus-ee</id>
            <name>camunda-bpm-nexus-ee</name>
            <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/repositories/camunda-bpm-ee</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>camunda-bpm-nexus</id>
            <name>camunda-bpm-nexus</name>
            <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

In src/main/resources

**camunda-license.txt**
  It contains license key

Comment: Did you provide your credentials for the nexus-ee?   You got user/pw for ee downloads and    must configure these creds for the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Your unchanged pom works fine on my environment. A difference between our environments is the Maven config.

From the cmd run *mvn clean package -X* to diagnose the issue. (Diagnose outside the IDE first to reduce complexity. IDEs can use their own Maven, override settings, etc.)

You will most likely find the issue to be either related to your credentials, your proxy config or firewall, or that your build is using another maven installation/config altogether (another setting.xml). The most reliable way for repository credentials to get picked up is to place a **settings.xml** with the credentials in you **user_home\.m2** directory.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>   
        <server>
          <id>camunda-bpm-ee</id>
          <username>myuser.name</username>
          <password><![CDATA[myPassword]]></password>
         </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>camunda-bpm</id>
            <repositories>
                <!-- spring maven repository -->
                <repository>
                    <id>springsource-repo</id>
                    <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
                </repository>
                <!-- camunda maven repository -->
                <repository>
                    <id>camunda-bpm-nexus</id>
                    <name>camunda-bpm-nexus</name>
                    <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>camunda-bpm-ee</id>
                    <name>camunda-bpm-ee</name>
                    <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/repositories/camunda-bpm-ee</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>camunda-bpm</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Also see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

A common mistake is mismatching ids between repository and credentials (here: camunda-bpm-ee).

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following solutions:
**Solution 1:**

> If you are using the enterprise edition, you can also use the
>   camunda.bpm.license-file property to provide a license file that is
>   inserted on application start. Or copy your license file under the
>   name camunda-license.txt to your src/main/resources.

More information: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/

**Solution 2:**
Try Maven Install: Steps are as follows:

> 1.Right click your project, choose Run As -> Maven install. Observe the output console to see the installation progress. After the installation is finished, you can continue to the next step.
>   2. Right click your Spring MVC project, choose Maven -> Update Project.
>   3. Choose your project and click OK. Wait until update process is finished.
>   4. If the error still yet, then do Project->Clean and then be sure you have selected our project directory and then do the follow
>   Project->Build.

**Solution 3:**

1. Delete the last modified jar from respective folders.
2. Select the project

   - Right Click -> Maven
   - Update project..

It will download all the missing Jars.

**Solution 4:**

> Uncheck Build automatically. Tick it again and started downloading
>   the jars.

Comment: I tried both ways, but my problem is with maven, it is not downloading "camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-ee" jar

Comment: Are you using eclipse ide?

Comment: Did you try maven install?
Steps:
1.Choose your project and click OK. Wait until update process is finished.
The error still yet, then do Project->Clean and then be sure you have selected our project directory and then do the follow Project->Build.
2. Right click your Spring MVC project, choose Maven -> Update Project. 3. Choose your project and click OK. Wait until update process is finished.
4. If the error still yet, then do Project->Clean and then be sure you have selected our project directory and then do the follow Project->Build.

Comment: I tried above steps also. 
Actually, I tried manually also to download camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-ee.jar but not able to download

Comment: yes, i am not able to found that jar, if anyone can share the link, then that would be really helpful

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.bpm.springboot/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter